# chrome browser not showing google ads for xhtml file

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to display google ads on xhtml file, but chorme browser down't show them up. The ads show on all other browsers I tried (Ie,firefox,opera) but chrome. Has anyone encountered this before? 
Small sample code:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <body>
<script language="javascript">

 google_ad_client = "pub-4942221729702985";
 google_ad_slot = "0095628928";
 google_ad_width = 728;
 google_ad_height = 90;
 </script>
 <script language="javascript"
 src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
 </script>
 </body>
   </html>
```

Thanks
Smitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is  google js file uses document.write, which is not allowed in a application/xhtml+xml page

I guess this will solve your problem

http://www.cromwell-intl.com/technical/google-adsense-and-xhtml.html

http://ejohn.org/blog/xhtml-documentwrite-and-adsense/

http://randsco.com/index.php/2005/11/10/serving_xhtml_with_the_right_mime_type

> The W3C recommends that ALL XHTML
>   documents be served as
>   "application/xhtml+xml". This is
>   because XHTML requires more strict
>   validation and the code doesn't
>   contain the myriad of diverse tags
>   (AKA "tag soup") that need be
>   supported in "text/html" (one benefit
>   is that XHTML renders faster).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It worked for me as explained in the link: http://www.cromwell-intl.com/technical/google-adsense-and-xhtml.html. 
Thanks once again!
Smitha